# Parallelizing GBM in R

Tags: r, regression, boosting

I'm able to parallelize `randomForest` based on the `foreach` function in the following way:

```
model_rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(250, 4), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
    randomForest(x = as.matrix(x.train), y = y.train, ntree=ntree, mtry = floor(ncol(x.train)/3))

prediction_rf <- predict(model_rf, x.test)
```

But trying to do the same thing with `gbm` (like below) does not work:

```
model_gbm <- foreach(ntree=rep(1250, 4), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE, .packages='gbm') %dopar%
    gbm.fit(x = as.matrix(x.train), y = y.train, distribution = "gaussian", n.trees = ntree, interaction.depth = 1, verbose = F)

prediction_gbm <- predict(model_gbm, x.test, n.trees = 5000)
```

This throws out the following error:

```
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4): Argument must be a list of randomForest objects>
```

What is the right way to combine and predict with gbm?

---

P.S.
I also tried using the `gbm` function with `n.cores=4` instead of the `gbm.fit` function, but I got the following error:

```
Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

Comment: Do you know what the `combine` function that you are attempting to use to combine `gbm` objects is?

Comment: @MatthewDrury It's the one used for combining trees from  randomForest. I'm trying to reuse the same for gbm.

Comment: How do you think the one for combining forests works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GBM is an inherently sequential algorithm. Each iteration depends on the results of the previous iteration. Contrast this with Random Forest where the algorithm is embarrassingly parallel -- every tree is independent of each other. This allows RF to be parallelized in ways GBM cannot.

The `combine` function you are using is from the `randomForest` package and it is crafted to specifically work on `randomForest` objects, as the error message says.

In summary you are trying to parallelize an inherently sequential algorithm and then combine the results using a function meant to concatenate independent randomForests.

If you're looking for performance gains for GBM models, check out the `xgboost` package. Parts of GBM *can* be parallel, such as the construction of the decision trees. This is the approach `xgboost` takes.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have pointed out, you cannot combine multiple gbm models as it is not an ensemble learning technique like randomForest.

However, the challenge in GBM is hyper parameter optimisation( finding the parameters that yield the best results ). This can parallelised easily with the help of big data system.

Comment: Possibly, you could expand somewhat your answer.

Comment: You can create a grid of hyper-parameters (learning rate, depth, min obs in nodes, etc...) and build a full model on each combination of parameters in parallel. The `foreach` package works great for such problems and I believe `caret` provides it as well although I prefer to roll my own.